# Telegram's Bot EXIF Data

Tags: telegram, chatbot

I have developed a chatbot in Telegram to get user's photo sent using the following API:

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage

And able to get the file use the following API:

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getfile

However, the file downloaded lost the EXIF attributes. Is telegram strip all the data? Or is there any way to get the original file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no way to get original image. Telegram optimize photo for user display.

but if user send the photo as `file` (document) then you can get the image without any change/optimize from Telegram.